# "Внимание" или "внимания"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать: "не обращать внимани***е***" или "не обращать внимани***я***"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Негативные глаголы (т.е. глаголы с частицей *не*) управляют формами двух падежей: винительного и родительного. В общем случае выбор падежа за автором текста.